# using awk to converting a column of data into a row

Tags: awk

I'm trying to convert a columns of data to a row using nawk

```
input=
1775
1800
1825
200
2850
3050
3075
3175
```

my code is:

```
nawk 'BEGIN{ORS=","}{print $0}'
```

but output is not included all data set in my input file.
can anyone help me through this...?

output:

```
,2850,3050,3075,3175,
```

Comment: `nawk '{$1=$1}1' RS= OFS=,   file`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew, @ yashar farzaneh, its working absolutly fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v OFS="," '
{ 
  gsub(/\r/,"")
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$0
}
END{
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

By looking OP's attempt it looks like OP may be on Sun o.s Solaris system, if this is the case change `awk` to `nawk`

Explanation:

Setting `OFS` as , to get output in comma separated values. Creating variable named val whose value is concatenating of its own value each time with comma. In END section of this code printing variable val to get all lines comma separated as per OP requirements.

---

---

Not tested on Sun o.s try if you have paste command there

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file;paste -sd',' Input_file
```

Comment: @yasharfarzaneh, could you please check if you have control M characters in your Input_file? Do like `cat -v Input_file` if you have them then you could remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file` and then try my code. Lemme know on same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks for your help and suggestions...I solved the issue in a silly way, but I'm not happy with this solution...!!                                                                  cat -v input_file | nawk 'BEGIN{ ORS=","}{print $0}'|nawk '{gsub("M","");print $0}' |sed 's/\^//g'

Comment: @yasharfarzaneh, in awk code itself I have taken care itself try now and let me know on same then?

Comment: @yasharfarzaneh, Glad that it helped you, you could select this answer as an correct one too, cheers

Answer (score 2):

You may do it with

```
nawk '{$1=$1}1' RS= OFS=, file > newfile
```

This will trim the string and replace all newlines with commas.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/OAaZem):

```
input="
1775
1800
1825
200
2850
3050
3075
3175"

nawk '{$1=$1}1' RS= OFS=, <<< "$input"
```

Output:

```
1775,1800,1825,200,2850,3050,3075,3175
```